# JBPM Deployments in Real Time

Tags: jbpm

I'm a newbie in JBPM development. I've questions regarding the development and deployment of jbpm applications.

1. How can the development be done in realtime projects? What will be the architecture followed for jbpm integration?
2. In real time projects, do we need separate kie server for jbpm deployment or can we use other servers like weblogic, tomcat for deploying the jars?
3. Is it possible to add some jbpm extension/jars to other servers and still use the business central?

Answer (score 0):

> How can the development be done in realtime projects? What will be the architecture followed for jbpm integration?

I'm not 100% sure whats your Question here.
If you want to know about the usage of a Workflow-Engine within a Solution that has Realtime requirements that is related to your exact definition of realtime. JBPM uses Java as Runtime. Executiontimes in Workflow-Engines are in general low (some ms for each step), but this depends on your individual business logic. Most of the performance loss is typically related to the network-layer. You can use integrated Workflow-Engines to reduce this overhead.

> In real time projects, do we need separate kie server for jbpm deployment or can we use other servers like weblogic, tomcat for deploying the jars?

JBPM's KIE-Server runs on default in a jboss wildfly application server. But you can deploy the app also on tomcat or other application server. It's also possible to create a cluster of kie-servers. As mentioned above - there are ways to integrate the Workflow-Engine in your own Codebase which reduces the network overhead.

> Is it possible to add some jbpm extension/jars to other servers and still use the business central?

JBPM KIE-Server and Business Central are seperated applications. Both runs on default in a jboss wildfly application server. Technically you can also host other apps on the application server in parallel.